# Themed Bootstrap5 table colors not working

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-themes

I themed my bootstrap 5.1.3 using Sass to add new colors to the panel.

I found that Bootstrap 5.1.3 can't be customized as Boostrap4 so I updated my scss file and it now looks like this :

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins";
$custom-theme-colors:map-merge($theme-colors, (
    "lightcornflowerblue": #8ECAE6,
    "bluegreen" : #219EBC,
    "prussianblue": #023047,
    "selectiveyellow": #FFB703,
    "tangerine": #FB8500,
));
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-theme-colors);
$theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");
$utilities-colors: map-merge($utilities-colors, $theme-colors-rgb);
$utilities-text-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "text");
$utilities-bg-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "bg");
$utilities-table-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "table");

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I checked and I can see this in the final css file :

```
.table-danger {
  --bs-table-bg: #f8d7da;
  --bs-table-striped-bg: #eccccf;
  --bs-table-striped-color: #000;
  --bs-table-active-bg: #dfc2c4;
  --bs-table-active-color: #000;
  --bs-table-hover-bg: #e5c7ca;
  --bs-table-hover-color: #000;
  color: #000;
  border-color: #dfc2c4; }
```

But the class "table-danger" doesn't have any effect !
And none of my custom color work for table colors...
Do you guys know what I missed in the process ? It was way easier in Bootstrap4 to have custom colors

I uploaded the .map file
Modified my scss to merge colors and all as it is now because my old bootstrap 4 scss wasn't working for most of the classes, now some of them work but table colors for example are not working.

Comment: It's in the first line of my message 5.1.3 if that's the question

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few problems.

1. Although the [docs aren't very clear](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/tables/#variants), you need to use both the `table` and `table-{variant}` class in the table to activate the table colors. So for example for `table-danger` use:

```
<table class="table table-danger">..</table>
```

2. **Bootstrap 5.3** now uses the `$table-variants` map, *not* `$utilities-table-colors`. So to add the new color variants you need to redefine/merge into `$table-variants` like...

```
$custom-table-variants: (
  "tangerine": $tangerine,
  "lightcornflowerblue": #8ECAE6
);

$table-variants: map-merge($table-variants, $custom-table-variants);
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/08u1mjECu3)

Comment: Hello Zim ! Thank you for your answer. I downloaded Bootstrap 5.3, created the scss you suggested and indeed it works. Th problem I have is the following :
On the demo you shared, we can see that the button and the table with class "danger" have different colors. Table colors are lighter and with bootstrap 4, creating a custom color used in a table had the same behavior.
With bootstrap 5.3, I now manage to use table-tangerine for example but the color is exactly the same as using bg-tangering, that wasn't the case and I'm expecting a behavior matching the one of danger for example. Any idea?

Comment: Another thing : doing what you suggested, I lost some colors for example class "alert-selectiveyellow" that was working before has no effect anymore now.